# i want to replace a path inside a yml file with another path in that file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, yaml

I have tried to replace a path inside a yml file using sed commands and also tried to comment the old path in that file. the commenting works fine but not specifically for that path. there are other paths in that file too. my yml file looks like:

```
  enabled: true
  close_eof: true
  #close_inactive: 1h
  paths:
      - /home/directory/another_directory/directory_20200910/*_*_*
```

now I want my file to look like

```
  enabled: true
  close_eof: true
  #close_inactive: 1h
  paths:
      - /home/directory/another_directory/directory_(today's date here-20201001)/*_*_*
```

PLEASE NOTE: the yml file has four spaces and then a "-" before the path

```
SPTH='/home/directory/another_directory'
sed -e '/$SPTH/ s/^#*/#/' -i test.yml
echo - /home/directory/another_directory/directory_date +%Y%m%d >> /home/test.yml
```

but this doesn't seem to work, another thing that is have tried is

```
sed -e '/home/ s/^#*/#/' -i test.yml
echo - /home/directory/another_directory/directory_`date +%Y%m%d` >> /home/test.yml
```

this works fine but it adds a comment on every path starting with `/home` and also echoes the path at the end of the file. therefore I have to use something with sed as I want to replace the path with current date.

Also please let me know if I would like to replace the folder's date with yesterday's date as I want to run the script after one day of the folder creation.

Comment: YAML tools need to parsed with a syntax aware parser like `yq`. Can you install such a tool? - https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/

Comment: i haven't tried installing that I was trying to directly replace it using sed without parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
date +%Y%m%d
20201001
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
sed "s#/directory_[0-9]*#/directory_${today}#" test.yml
```

Output:

```
enabled: true
close_eof: true
#close_inactive: 1h
paths:
    - /home/directory/another_directory/directory_20201001/*_*_*
```

Use sed with option -i to save the Output

Comment: Thanks for this. I am almost there. Can you please tell me if I want to change the date to yesterday in the same script, how is that possible? As I will be running the script after one day of creation of that date folder

Comment: i have achieved it by myself thank you.
I did

`date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d

yesterday=$(date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d)`

Answer (score 0):

Using simple text processing tools for YAML will not always work correct. Such a solution may be acceptable if you know that your YAML input will always have a certain format.

Assuming you want to replace **all occurrences** of

```
/home/directory/another_directory/directory_<any_number>/*_*_*
```

with

```
/home/directory/another_directory/directory_<today_s_date>/*_*_*
```

you could use

```
sed -e 's#\(/home/directory/another_directory/directory_\)[0-9]*\(/\*_\*_\*\)#\1'$(date +%Y%m%d)'\2#' test.yml
```

With your example input this prints

```
enabled: true
close_eof: true
#close_inactive: 1h
paths:
    - /home/directory/another_directory/directory_20201001/*_*_*
```

Of course you can use option `-i` to replace the input file instead of printing the modified data. (Make sure the `sed` command works correct because you may lose your original input data.)

If it is a requirement to have the path in variable `SPTH`, the script can be modified like this

```
SPTH='/home/directory/another_directory'
sed -e 's#\('$SPTH'/directory_\)[0-9]*\(/\*_\*_\*\)#\1'$(date +%Y%m%d)'\2#' test.yml
```

---

If you want to have yesterday's date instead of today's date, simply replace

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

with

```
date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d
```

This option `-d` is not defined by the POSIX standard, but is available with GNU `date` on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

there's a couple of problems i see:

#### what's that regex supposed to do in the first place?

the regular expression `/home/ s/^#*/#/` will perform a replacment on all lines containing `home` (cool), but it will replace any number of `#` at the beginning of the line with a single `#`.

that is: it will remove all `#` at the beginning of each line, and then add a new one to each line (as `^#*` will match zero leading hashes as well).

this is probably *not* what you want.

#### single-quotes will prevent the expansion of variables

`sed -e '/$SPTH/ s/^#*/#/'` will perform the substitution on all lines that contain the literal `$SPTH` (regardless of whether there's a shell variable `SPTH` and what it's contents are).

this is probably *not* what you want.

if you want `$SPTH` to be expanded, you need double-quotes (`"`)

(but of course, then you run into problems since the expanded value of `$SPTH` contains slashes, interfering with the sed-expression itself).

## solution.

to simply replace the current directory, use something like:

```
SPTH='/home/lt-1027'
sed \
  -e "s|^\( *-  *${SPTH}\)/.*/\*_\*_\*|\1/$(date +%Y%m%d)/*_*_*|" \
  -i test.yml
```

this uses the pipe `|` as the delimiting character, to avoid problems with the slash in `${SPTH}`.
it captures the indentation, dash and start of the file (up to the end of `${SPTH}`) into the capture-group `\1`, which is then used in the replacement, so the replacment text has the same indentation as the original one (hopefully keeping your yaml intact)

if you want to keep the original path and comment it out, use

```sh
sed \
  -e "s|^\(\( *-  *${SPTH}\)/.*/\*_\*_\*\)$|#\1\n\2/$(date +%Y%m%d)/*_*_*|" \
  -i test.yml
```

this will capture the entire old line into reference `\1` (so we can replace it with a commented-out version of itself by prefixing `#`); the indentation is now captured into `\2`)

Comment: You can use `&` in the replacement instead of an additional capture group for the whole line.